# Spring boot STATELESS application with JWT auth and csrf token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, csrf

I have Spring boot application with JWT auth which works great!
But I have disabled csrf with STATELESS Policy:

```
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

This Rest API is for SPA React application. I read that when I'm using JWT token then I don't need to set csrf token. Does JWT works like csrf protection(HOW)? I think that this is not csrf protection.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm facing the same question and there is no explanation. In spring security they mentioned that even stateless setups are not protected by definition.

Answer (score 8):

CSRF attacks are about taking advantage of the fact that browsers always includes cookies in requests to the requested server (including session IDs), So the attacker pretend that he is the genune user while performing malicious action .

If your endpoints are stateless (that means you are not using cookies for authentication) then you do not need CSRF protection .

Comment: Just to add - consider that when using a SPA, the user's application (re: session) state is stored locally on the client, yet while using an older style MVC, user state is stored at the server and requires a round trip over the network to utilize. Because of the network communication component, MVC needs an additional CSRF token to prevent impersonators from hijacking another user's session, while SPA inherently does not need it at all.